# Casting UIButton to UIViewRepresentable causes error when running

Tags: swiftui

I am getting the following error when running my SwftUI project where i have added the GoogleCast Framework

`Found unexpected null pointer value while trying to cast value of type 'UIButton' (0x1350423c8) to 'UIViewController' (0x1b90589b0)`

I have used UIViewRepresentable to get the Button to show correctly in SwiftUI:

```
import GoogleCast
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct GoogleCastButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    let tintColor: UIColor
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    
    private let frame: CGRect
    private let castButton: GCKUICastButton
    
    init(
        tintColor: UIColor = .gray,
        width: CGFloat = 24,
        height: CGFloat = 24
    ) {
        self.tintColor = tintColor
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: frame)
        castButton.tintColor = tintColor
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIButton {
        castButton
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIButton, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct GoogleCastButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GoogleCastButton()
            .fixedSize()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

I have also tried UIViewRepresentableContext:

```
struct GoogleCastButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    let tintColor: UIColor
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    
    private let frame: CGRect
    private let castButton: GCKUICastButton
    
    init(
        tintColor: UIColor = .gray,
        width: CGFloat = 24,
        height: CGFloat = 24
    ) {
        self.tintColor = tintColor
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        
        frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        castButton = GCKUICastButton(frame: frame)
        castButton.tintColor = tintColor
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> GCKUICastButton {
        castButton
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GCKUICastButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        castButton.tintColor = tintColor
    }
}
```

If i comment the button from within my SwiftUI app it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because i wasnt calling GCKCastContext in appDelegate properly using UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor, i ended up scrapping this method and calling it in my `: App` class directly